# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7000 in POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, server, postman, vpn

When I try to access APIs on my remote server which I am connected through VPN, I get this error. Any help is appreciated.

[image: screenshot of errors]

Comment: there is no server listening on URI, or as you said behind VPN, it is not able to connect via VPN, you will need to add rules in VPN to allow some origins.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted you are using a vpn, what type ?

1-Split tunneling VPN - Can use Postman directly to the API as long as the API server/Firewall/Load Balancer accepts traffic from your local workstation/asset

2-Tunnel mode-tunnel mode - Can use Postman via proxy settings to the API as long as the API server/Firewall/Load Balancer accepts traffic from your local workstation/asset, see the following link [Postman - Using a proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

3-Tunnel mode-tunnel mode with Internet Connection Shaing disabled - In this case you can only use Postman on a remote server/workstation (within the private network) where the traffic is accepted by the API server/Firewall/Load Balancer